# Logback: how write logs to file

Tags: java, gradle, logback

I need to add logback to my project.
This is my test class:

```
public class Head implements Runnable {
    Thread trd;

    Head() {
        trd = new Thread(this);
        trd.start();
    }
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Head.class);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        MDC.put("logName", "LOG_NAME");
        logger.warn("test1");
        logger.info("test2");
        logger.error("test");
        MDC.remove("logName");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String URL = "logback-test.xml";
        System.out.println(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(URL));
        int count = 1;
        while(count<=3){
            Head head = new Head();
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my logback-test.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">

        <discriminator>
            <key>logName</key>
            <defaultValue>test</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>
        <sift>
            <appender name="FILE-${logName}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
                <file>D:/tmp/${logName}.log</file>
                <append>false</append>
                <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                    <pattern>%d [%thread] %level %mdc %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
                </layout>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>

    <root level="ALL">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I have added following groovy dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.21'
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jcl-over-slf4j', version: '1.7.21'
compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.1.7'
compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version: '1.1.7'
compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-access', version: '1.1.7'
```

As result I expect logs would be saved into file D:/tmp/LOG_NAME.log, but logs are writing only into console. Could you help to fix this?

After adding debug option I got error:

```
Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
         Reported exception:
              file:/D:/my_tests/build/resources/main/logback-test.xml
              groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener.addNewInstanceToContext() is applicable for argument types: (ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext) values: [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default]]
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1500)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1486)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferConfigurator.run(GafferConfigurator.groovy:65)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferConfigurator$run.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferConfigurator.run(GafferConfigurator.groovy:44)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.gaffer.GafferUtil.runGafferConfiguratorOn(GafferUtil.java:43)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:67)
at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
at com.aerlingus.uita.utils.Head.<clinit>(Head.java:20)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
```

Comment: Given that you are not setting console appender to your root logger, and you see the log message in console but not log file, I suspect your `logback-test.xml` is not in the runtime classpath.  You may turn on Logback debug mode.  It can be done by changing config file to `<configuration debug="true">`, but given that the config may not be loaded, you may choose to set the system property `logback.debug=true`.  It should give you info on what went wrong

Comment: a bit off topic: 1. The threading-related code you wrote is far from satisfactory. Create a thread in ctor and refer `this` and start it right away... that's a horrible idea.  2. Next time if you want to try out something new, make a skeleton as plain as possible so you don't need to worry things goes wrong in other part (e.g. your multi-threading etc). Just make a extrememely simple class with one logging statement in `main()`, and make use of a simple file appender instead of sifting appender, and make that works before you add other thing onto it

Comment: I was using Maven 3, as a simple Java project, with the exact dependency you mentioned.  The things works fine.  I saw you have raised a related question and it mentioned you are using Gradle.  How are you running your code? I bet if it is a simple Java project, and you build it, set up correct classpath, and run it as a Java app, it should work.  I suspect your problem have somthng to do Groovy

Comment: I use gradle as build tool and have dependencies on groovy projects

Comment: My personal recommendation, as I said before, is to try it out bit by bit: first a minmal gradle project with a minimal class to write log using a minimal `logback.xml`.  If it works, make your `logback.xml` a more real-life one (like what you have in the question).  If it works, add your other dependencies bit by bit.  By going thru this process you should be able to easily identify what is the cause of the problem

Comment: So the reason was in one of third party dependencies: it has logback.groovy, so my config file was ignored

Comment: hm... that's strange, because from the debug message of logback, it is actually reading your `logback-test.xml`.  Anyway, at least it align with one of the possibilities I mentioned in my answer lol :P  Anyway, you should report to author of that library.  Including logging config, or declaring dependency of any SLF4J impl is considered a bad practice

Answer (score -1):

I have used your code (with some minor changes on the log file path, from `D:/tmp/` to `/tmp/`).  It worked as expected.

Which means, what you provided here is correct.  The problem is caused by something else.

Given that you can see your log messages in console, it is most probably that the `logback-test.xml` is not read.  Either there is a `logback.groovy` in classpath, or your `logback-test.xml` is not even in classpath.

Please provide system property `logback.debug=true` (e.g. by `-Dlogback.debug=true`) and inspect the message in console printed by Logback, to identify your problem

Comment: I got error after adding debug, details in question

Answer (score -3):

this logback.xml file should help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="LOG_PATH" value="/tmp/name.log" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-AUDIT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/debug.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/archived/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-ERROR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/error.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/archived/error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.yourapp" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: It means nothing just to throw out a working but irrelevant config

Comment: @AdrianShum irrelevant? sorry but I think the code IS relevant, and should help OP

Comment: So, what is the problem of OP then?  He should not use Sifting Appender? It is a problem not to set all other logger?  If you spot the problem in his config and you fix it, that's fine, but now you are just giving some irrelevant config which does something totally different from what OP is originally doing.  I don't think that's an appropriate "answer"

Comment: I found it helpful

Answer (score -3):

can you try below log xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<property name="DEV_HOME" value="c:/logs" />
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">

    <discriminator>
        <key>logName</key>
        <defaultValue>test</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    <sift>
        <appender name="FILE-${logName}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>D:/tmp/${logName}.log</file>
            <append>false</append>
            <encoder  class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>%d [%thread] %level %mdc %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
            <rollingPolicy
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
              <FileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/${logName}.%i.log.zip
              </FileNamePattern>
              <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
              <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        </appender>
    </sift>
</appender>

<root level="ALL">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Same comment as the other answer: This is not an appropriate answer to OP.  And, I have actually tried OP's config and it works.  Unless you can tell the significance of the difference in config that can cause the problem, it is surely not an answer that we expect in SO

Comment: Sorry it is not new logback.xml, but it is same logback xml of OP but i modified it with RollingFileAppender.FileAppender appends log events to a file. and RollingFileAppender extends FileAppender to backup the log files when they reach a certain size. may be the content size is issue because of which it is not printing in file but it is printing in console. Also i have added rollingPolicy and triggeringPolicy for the same. Hope you got ans for your question of significance of the difference

Comment: Sorry to assume it to be a new logback.xml.  I assumed so because there was some irrelevant changes like `<property>`.  However, my argument still holds: Your answer should tell what's wrong, instead of just throw out a config which no one can understand your intention