# Logback log file empty

Tags: java, logback

What do I need to change to have the logs get written on the log file using Logback?

```
   dependencies {
           implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3',
                         'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3'
           api 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30'
                 }



 <configuration debug="true">
        <appender name="FILE" class ="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
          <file>logs\logfile.log</file>
          <append>true</append>
          <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
          <encoder>
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
           </encoder>
        </appender>
    
        <appender name="STDOUT"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <Target>System.out</Target>
          <encoder>
             <pattern> .....</pattern>
           </encoder>
        </appender>
    
        <root level="DEBUG">
         <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
         <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        </root>
  </configuration>
```

In Java Class:

```
 private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
    public static void main(String[] args){
    log.debug("hello");
    }
```

The file `logfile.log` gets created under logs folder but it's empty  and Console does show the log.

Comment: What logback dependencies are you using? See if this helps anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534044/logback-how-write-logs-to-file

Comment: logback-classic  and slf4j-api

Comment: Is this exactly what you have? <appender name="FILE" class =ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender"> If it is you are missing a double quote after equals sign. The correct configuration is: <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">

Comment: it was a typo in the question. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you missed the *logback-core* dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.10</version>
</dependency>
```

or

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.10'
    ...
}
```

In addition to the other two you already have.

Other thing to do is to update to the latest versions of each dependency and see if the problem still occurs.

Reference: https://sematext.com/blog/logback-tutorial/ or https://www.baeldung.com/logback

Comment: Actually I have them as gradle dependencies.
implementation
'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3','ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3' 
api 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30'

Comment: I have added the dependencies in the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Adding depedency of logback-core was missing and also immediateFlush should be true or simply be removed.